# 'FastText' object has no attribute 'vocab'

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, text-processing, fasttext

I want to use Fasttext in my program, but that error prevent me to do it. I want to create embedding matrix for my program, with following code:

```
model = gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model(EMBEDDING_FILE)

EMBEDDING_DIM = 300
nb_words = min(MAX_NB_WORDS, len(word_index)) + 1
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((nb_words, EMBEDDING_DIM))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    if word in model.vocab:
        embedding_matrix[i] = model.word_vec(word)
print('Null word embeddings: %d' % np.sum(np.sum(embedding_matrix, axis=1) == 0))
```

Comment: The keyed word vectors are stored in model.wv.vocab